# Iterating over dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

In the code below i am trying to loop over the variable "Genome" which contains a snippet of genetic code. I'm initializing an array stored in variable "skew" which keeps running score of genetic letters is encounters. For example, every time a "C" is encountered i want skew[i] to equal skew[i-1]-1 and every time a "G" is encountered i want skew[i] to equal skew[i-1]+1. So i'm basically keeping score of the ratio of G to C in a segment of genetic code. When i run the code below i get "Keyerror: 23". I know Python throws a keyerror when it can't access a dict item but i don't know how to fix my code. Please help!!

```
def skew(Genome):
    skew = {}
    n = len(Genome)
    skew[0] = 0
    for i in range(0,n):
        #skew[i] = skew[i-1]
        if Genome[i] == "G":
            for j in (1,n):
                skew[j] = skew[j-1]+1
        elif Genome[i] == "C":
            for j in (1,n):
                skew[j] = skew[j-1]-1  
        else:
            for j in (1,n):
                skew[j]=skew[j-1]
    return skew


Genome="CCGTTCTTCGCTCTAGTTACAGCG"


print skew(Genome)
```

Comment: `range(0, n)` should be `range(n)`. The 0 is redundant.

Comment: It would also have detected the bug, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `skew = {}` into `skew = []` to initialize a list instead of a dictionary.

And to ensure all `skew[j]` does not access out of list boundary, you could initialize `skew` like

```
skew = [0] * n
```

Comment: Then it will just say "list index out of range" for like "skew[j] = skew[j-1]-1
"

Comment: Added about how to initialize a large enough list.

Comment: While I agree on the usage of a list, this would just have made the bug harder to detect. Maybe initialize to None instead of 0 so that it is more likely to produce an error if one entry is missing: `[None] * n`.

Answer (score 1):

`for j in (1,n)`: you are missing `range`. So `j` takes value 24 right away and your code breaks (j-1 = 23 is not in the dict yet). Change to `for j in range(1,n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution.  I presume it's useful to calculate skew for other letter pairs, so I added that too.

`delta` is a generator expression that determines the changes (+1, -1, 0).
`accumulate` generates the running sum of the deltas.

```
import itertools as it

def skew(Genome, plus="G", minus="C"):
    delta = (1 if c == plus else -1 if c == minus else 0 for c in Genome)
    return list(it.accumulate(delta))

skew(Genmome)
```

returns

```
[-1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -2, -2, -2, -3, -2, -3, -3, -4, -4, -4, -3, -3, -3, -3, 4, -4, -3, -4, -3]
```

**Edit**
An equivalent Python 2.7 solution:

```
def skew(Genome, plus="G", minus="C"):
    delta = [1 if c == plus else -1 if c == minus else 0 for c in Genome]
    for i in range(1, len(delta)):
        delta[i] += delta[i-1]
    return delta
```

Comment: this might be a good solution but unfortunately i'm not able to test it properly since it's giving me the error "'module' object has no attribute 'accumulate' 
"

Comment: I added an equivalent solution for Python 2.7

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I can't upvote you because my rep is below 15.